# Amazon S3 - Connect storage to the docker image like network disc

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, kubernetes

I am looking for information but I can't find it. Is it possible to attach Amazon S3 storage to the Docker container so that it is via the application (Spring Boot) as a disk? If so, how to do it? If it is important, the docker image is managed by kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to take a look at the product [Min.io](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide.html).
Its client has nice features that allow you to use simple FS commands to operate S3 storage from your container:

```
ls        list buckets and objects
mb        make a bucket
rb        remove a bucket
cat       display object contents
head      display first 'n' lines of an object
pipe      stream STDIN to an object
share     generate URL for temporary access to an object
cp        copy objects
mirror    synchronize objects to a remote site
find      search for objects
sql       run sql queries on objects
stat      stat contents of objects
lock      set and get object lock configuration
retention set object retention for objects with a given prefix
legalhold set object legal hold for objects
diff      list differences in object name, size, and date between buckets
rm        remove objects
event     manage object notifications
watch     watch for object events
policy    manage anonymous access to objects
admin     manage MinIO servers
session   manage saved sessions for cp command
config    manage mc configuration file
update    check for a new software update
version   print version info
```

For convenience, you may add shell aliases to override your common Unix tools.

```
alias ls='mc ls'
alias cp='mc cp'
alias cat='mc cat'
alias mkdir='mc mb'
alias pipe='mc pipe'
alias find='mc find'
```

It also has native Java (Pyton, Golang, .NET, Haskel) client:

- [MinIO Java SDK for Amazon S3 Compatible Cloud Storage](https://docs.min.io/docs/java-client-quickstart-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is an object storage and not a block storage or file storage and you should not attach it to a container. For any practical purpose you should be able to use the s3 storage from the spring boot application using AWS SDK or API.

Answer (score 0):

With **kubernetes** you can use block storage such as [AWSElasticBlockStore](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/#awselasticblockstore) out of the box.

If you want to use object storage like **S3**, this is also possible however far more complicated. If you are still interested in implementing specifically **S3** storage on your **kubernetes cluster**, [this](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/virtualization/Kubernetes-shared-storage-with-S3-backend/) article describes very well the whole procedure.